# Domino Objects COMException: 'Out of memory'

Tags: c#, com, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

When I call `NotesDXLExporterClass.Export` on a `NotesDocumentClass` object that has a very large attachment, I get a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Out of memory'` exception.

I was hoping to resolve this by setting `NotesDXLExporter.OmitRichtextAttachments` to `true`, but it looks like this property is not available through COM (1).

What are my options here to get around this issue?

(1) [Differences between accessing Domino Objects through either LotusScript or COM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_ACCESSING_THE_DOMINO_OBJECTS_THROUGH_COM_SPECIFIC.html)

**Note 4:** `NotesXMLProcessor` is not implemented in COM. `NotesDXLExporter` and `NotesDXLImporter` implement `ExitOnFirstFatalError`, `Log`, and `LogComment`, rather than inheriting them. )

Edit:

When I open `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\domobj.tlb` in `Oleview.exe` and look at the `NotesDXLExporterClass` interface I only see the following:

```
[
  uuid(29131437-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7)
]
dispinterface NOTESDXLEXPORTER {
    properties:
        [id(0x00000bf6)        
]
        VARIANT FORCENOTEFORMAT;
        [id(0x00000bfa)        
]
        VARIANT OUTPUTDOCTYPE;
        [id(0x00000bfb)        
]
        BSTR DOCTYPESYSTEM;
        [id(0x00000f1e), readonly        
]
        BSTR LOG;
        [id(0x00000f1f)        
]
        BSTR LOGCOMMENT;
        [id(0x00000f20)        
]
        VARIANT EXITONFIRSTFATALERROR;
    methods:
        [id(0x00000f28)]
        void SETINPUT(VARIANT INPUT);
        [id(0x00000f29)]
        void SETOUTPUT(VARIANT OUTPUT);
        [id(0x00000f2a)]
        void PROCESS();
};
```

Comment: How "very large"? If it's around 2G, it will never work.

Comment: It is only 36MB.

Comment: Actually it is 364MB

Comment: 364M is quite big indeed. Are you running x86 (vs x64)? Depending on how it's stored, the real size may be more, plus depending on how export is coded, you may very well hit a real out of memory limit. Especially if the whole thing works with smaller attachments.

Comment: you find any solution on above problem

Answer (score 0):

The document to which you've linked (and also my local Notes Help) doesn't say that `NotesDXLExporter.OmitRichtextAttachments` isn't available in COM. Did you try using that property and get an error?

If `NotesDXLExporter.OmitRichtextAttachments` isn't available, are you able to develop an agent in the relevant Domino database (or in another database created for this purpose) that acts as a go-between?

I'm thinking an agent could take the note id of the target document via `NotesAgent.Run`, and export that document's DXL to a field (which might have to be rich text if the DXL is more than 32kB) in another temporary document. Your code should call that agent via COM, get the resulting temporary document, read the DXL from its field, then delete the temporary document.
This seems overly complex, but it's the only solution that occurs to me.

Comment: Please see the edit I made to my original post. TLDR is that I am not seeing that property in the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code as a LotusScript agent.

If it fails, the problem is inherent in the classes, not in the COM implementation and there's not going to be much you can do other than trying a more up-to-date version of Notes/Domino.

If it works, a potential workaround would be to have your COM code invoke a LotusScript agent on the server to do this part of the work.